# Python find max number of combinations in binary

Tags: python, list, binary

Hi I'm trying to figure out a function where given a length n of a list [x1, x2... xn], how many digits would be needed for a base 2 number system to assign a unique code to each value in the list.

For example, one digit can hold two unique values:

```
x1 0
x2 1
```

two digits can hold four:

```
x1 00
x2 01
x3 10
x4 11
```

etc. I'm trying to write a python function calcBitDigits(myListLength) that takes this list length and returns the number of digits needed. calcBitDigits(2) = 1, calcBitDigits(4) = 2, calcBitDigits(3) = 2, etc.

Comment: what you are looking for is the mathematical function log base 2 (rounded up). You can find a bunch of different math libraries to do this for you.

Comment: `x = int(log(n,2))+1` - This will give you the number of bits needed.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl: note that `math.log` has an optional `base` argument.

Comment: @Warren Sorry, I wanted to be safe. I have used like 5 languages in the last week... I should have checked the docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> for i in range(10):
...    print i, i.bit_length()
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 2
4 3
5 3
6 3
7 3
8 4
9 4
```

I'm not clear on exactly what it is you want, but it *appears* you want to subtract 1 from what `bit_length()` returns - or maybe not ;-)

On third thought ;-), maybe you really want this:

```
def calcBitDigits(n):
    return (n-1).bit_length()
```

At least that gives the result you said you wanted in each of the examples you gave.

Note:  for an integer `n` > 0, `n.bit_length()` is the number of bits needed to represent `n` in binary.  `(n-1).bit_length()` is really a faster way of computing `int(math.ceil(math.log(n, 2)))`.

Clarification:  I understand the original question now ;-)  Here's how to think about the answer:  if you have `n` items, then you can assign them unique codes using the `n` integers in `0` through `n-1` inclusive.  How many bits does that take?  The number of bits needed to express `n-1` (the largest of the codes) in binary.  I hope that makes the answer obvious instead of mysterious ;-)

As comments pointed out, the argument gets strained for `n=1`.  It's a quirk then that `(0).bit_length() == 0`.  So watch out for that one!

Comment: Interesting function... Actually, the OP has it wrong, and python has it right :). It *does* take 3 bits to store 4 - 100. - Also this is much more pythonic (and efficient) than using logs I would think.

Comment: @korylprince, that's the number 4, 2 bits is enough for 4 _items_

Comment: @korylprince, yup, but I don't think that's what the OP really wants.

Comment: @gnibbler ahh yes I see that now.

Comment: I think it's `(i-1).bit_length()`

Comment: @TimPeters `calcBitDigits(1) == 0`?!?!

Comment: @thefourtheye, yes. if there's only one item you don't need any bits to determine which one it is

Comment: @gnibbler But, OP wants to know number of digits needed to assign a unique code. How can he assign a unique code with 0 digits?

Comment: @thefourtheye, yes, but `int(math.ceil(math.log(n, 2)))` also returns 0 for `n=1`.  It's what we in the trade call an annoying end case ;-)  If there's only 1 item, the empty code is unique - LOL.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following -

```
import math
int(math.ceil(math.log(x,2)))
```

where `x` is the list length.

Edit:

For `x = 1`, we need to have a separate case that would return `1`. Thanks @thefourtheye for pointing this out.

Comment: This is also wrong, I think. When `x == 1`, this returns `0`. OP wants to know number of digits needed to assign a unique code. How can he assign a unique code with 0 digits?

Comment: @thefourtheye that needs to be covered separately.

Answer (score 1):

I am not comfortable with the other answers, since most of them fail at the corner case (when n == 1). So, I wrote this based on [Tim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20233260/1903116).

```
def calcBitDigits(n):
    if n <= 0: return 0
    elif n <= 2: return 1
    return (n-1).bit_length()

for i in range(10):
    print i, calcBitDigits(i)
```

**Output**

```
0 0
1 1
2 1
3 2
4 2
5 3
6 3
7 3
8 3
9 4
```

Comment: Oops! Check my edit:  you had `return return` in the last part, and I deleted one of them.  But maybe you meant `else: return` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = int(log(n,2))+1
```

`x` will be the number of bits required to store the integer value `n`.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you don't want to use `.bit_length`, here's another way to find it.

```
from itertools import count
def calcBitDigits(n):
    return next(i for i in count() if 1<<i >= n)
```